# Limiting form number input to 2 Decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 3 number input fields used to input the price,discount, and discounted price of an item, with the discounted price displaying up to 2 decimals.

I've looked around the net, and here on SO for ways to limit the numbers to 2 Decimals places and am currently using the following code

Code:

```
$('#ItemPercent').change(function(){
        var percent=$('#ItemPercent').val();
        var price=$('#ItemPrice').val();
        var discountpercent=percent / 100;
        var discountamt=price * discountpercent;
        var discountamt=Math.floor(discountamt * 100)/100;
        var discountamtrounded=discountamt.toFixed(2);
        $('#ItemDiscountPrice').val(price - discountamtrounded);
});
```

However, even when using the code above, the discounted price is not showing 2 decimal places.

E.g

E.g

```
$129.99 <----ItemPrice
10% <------Discount %
$117.00000000000001 <------ ItemDiscountPrice.
```

Where the example above is what i am currently getting when i test run my code.

How would i limit the numbers displayed to just 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
$('#ItemDiscountPrice').val((price - discountamtrounded).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: ... I cant believe i missed that! I was looking at rounding the discountamt and cmpletely forgot about ItemDiscountPrice. I'll accept the answer when 10 mins have passed. Thanks!